# Back4App angular hosting

Tags: javascript, angular, back4app

When Uploading a compiled angular-6 app to back4app and following their Docs 
https://www.back4app.com/docs/javascript/angular-template 
I always get Error (403 - Forbidden) in the Chrome console although I already added the Keys required to connect to the service in the environment.ts File [image: Error Screen Shot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double-check that the files are in the public folder because the 403 error is related to the lack of permission. Another point are the reserved words from Parse, that can affect this, example: /login.